# Chosen SHA variant is not supported

Tags: cordova, twitter, ionic-framework, twitter-oauth, ngcordova

I'm developing a mobile application with Ionic and I have to connect with the Twitter API.
So I use ng-cordova and `$cordovaAuth`. But when I do :

```
$cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret);
```

I got the following error :

> error Error: Chosen SHA variant is not supported
>      at Error (native)
>      at new t (http://192.168.1.19:8100/lib/sha-js/sha1.js:12:276)
>      at Object.createSignature (http://192.168.1.19:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:6120:38)
>      at Object.twitter (http://192.168.1.19:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:5623:55)
>      at Object.initialize (http://192.168.1.19:8100/js/services/twitter.js:18:18)

So, the problem comes from the `sha1.js`, I included this in my `index.html`

It would be nice if you could help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, the last version of jsSHA doesn't work with ngCordova. It works with the version 1.6.0
See : https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/93#issuecomment-113279865

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the new version of jsSHA is not supported. Use version 1.6.0 of jsSHA instead.
[versions jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/releases)